# Unable to install IIS-NetFXExtensibility

Tags: asp.net, iis, chef-infra

I am executing the following recipes on the [IIS Cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/iis).

1. mod_application_initialization
2. mod_aspnet

I get the following exception in the opsworks log on AWS.

```
[2016-04-04T01:33:41+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception 
[2016-04-04T01:33:41+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers 
[2016-04-04T01:33:41+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete 
[2016-04-04T01:33:41+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/chef/runs/a66904e6-ad9e-429c-a066-6fe14c0e5494/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out 
[2016-04-04T01:33:41+00:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: windows_feature[IIS-NetFxExtensibility] (install-iis::mod_aspnet line 12) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0, 42, 127, 3010], but received '50' 
---- Begin output of C:\Windows\sysnative\dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /norestart   ---- 
STDOUT: Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool  
Version: 6.3.9600.17031  

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031  

Enabling feature(s)  

Error: 50  

The operation is complete but IIS-NetFxExtensibility feature was not enabled.  
A required parent feature may not be enabled. You can use the /enable-feature /all option to automatically enable each parent feature from the following list. If the parent feature(s) are already enabled, refer to the log file for further diagnostics.  
NetFx3, NetFx3ServerFeatures, NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45  

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log 
STDERR:  
---- End output of C:\Windows\sysnative\dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /norestart   ---- 
Ran C:\Windows\sysnative\dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /norestart   returned 50
```

What must I add to the code to get this to work ?

```
include_recipe 'iis'

if Opscode::IIS::Helper.older_than_windows2008r2?
  log 'Application Initialization module is not supported on Windows 2008 or lower, ignoring'
else
  windows_feature 'IIS-ApplicationInit' do
    action :install
  end
end
```

-------------Update-------------
Access the run log [here](https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/chef-run-logs/25011829-a9da-4734-bd69-4d8da6d315dc.txt)

Comment: Please include the full client output.

Comment: I have provided a link to the run log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NetFx3, NetFx3ServerFeatures, NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45`

You'll need to enable those features too, just like you enable `'IIS-ApplicationInit'` (also before that one).